# Dimension of incidence variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

**Context:**

Let $\mathbb{K}$ an algebrically closed field of zero caracteristic.

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \leq m$.

Let's denote $\text{Gr}_{m-k}(\mathbb{K}^m)$ the Grassmannian of $\mathbb{K}^m$ (i.e. the set of subspaces of $\mathbb{K}^m$ of dimension $m-k$). In addition, we denote $M_{nm}(\mathbb{K})$ the space of $n \times m$ matrices.

We define the incidence variety by
$$\Gamma_k = \{(A,F) \in M_{nm}(\mathbb{K}) \times Gr_{m-k}(\mathbb{K}^m) \, | \, F \subset \ker A\}$$
We want to find the dimension of $\Gamma_k$ as a variety.

**How I started:**
Let's denote $\pi_2 : M_{nm}(\mathbb{K}) \times Gr_{m-k}(\mathbb{K}^m) \to Gr_{m-k}(\mathbb{K}^m)$ the projection to the second factor. In a first time, we will fix $F \in Gr_{m-k}(\mathbb{K}^m)$. The purpose is to calculate $\dim \pi_2^{-1}(\{F\}) \cap \Gamma_k$.

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\pi_2^{-1}(\{F\}) \cap \Gamma_k & = & \{(A,F) \, | \, F \subset \ker A\} \\ & \simeq & \{A \in M_{nm}(\mathbb{K}) \, | \, \forall x \in F, \, Ax = 0\}
\end{eqnarray*}
So $\pi_2^{-1}(\{F\}) \cap \Gamma_k$ is a vector space. Let's calculate its dimension. We consider
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
\varphi_F& : & M_{nm}(\mathbb{K}) & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{K}^{(m-k)n} \\ & & A & \longmapsto & \begin{pmatrix} Au_1 \\ Au_2 \\ \vdots \\ Au_{m-k} \end{pmatrix}
\end{array}$$
where $F = \text{vect}(u_1, \dots, u_{m-k})$.

At this point, I wasn't able to show that $\varphi_F$ is well defined and that it is surjective. But assuming that, and by using the rank theorem we have
$$nm = \dim \ker \varphi_F + (m-k)n.$$
So
$$\dim \ker \varphi_F = nm - nm + nk = nk.$$
We conclude then that
$$\dim(\pi_2^{-1}(\{F\}) \cap \Gamma_k) = nk.$$
**My questions are:** Are the above treatment of the question correct? and how can we deduce the dimension of $\Gamma_k$ ?

Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: You are on the right path. Since the fibers of $\pi_2$ all have the same dimension and it is onto the Grassmannian, you get $\dim \Gamma_k= nK+\dim \mathbb{G}(m-k,m)=nk+(m-k)k=(n+m-k)k$.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you so much for your answer. If you allow me, do you know why $\varphi_F$ is surjective? Especially, why the matrix $A$ that we take is the same at each line? I think it is a basic result of linear algebra but I don't see it. Thanks again !